# Implementación de Balizas con Altbeacons

Tags: android, android-volley

Estoy realizando una App que detecte balizas y poder mostrar la información que traen desde su respectiva API. Estoy utilizando la librería **altbeacons** para el scanner y **volley** para el llamado de la API.

Logro traer la información y mostrarla, pero lo que quiero conseguir es agruparlas y mandar una notificación para cuando aparecen en la región. Luego, guardar la información, y lo más importante es que el scanner de balizas se ejecute en el fondo sin necesidad de abrir la app.

Les dejo mi código del MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);

    //codigo beacons
    beaconRegion = new Region(UNIQUE_ID,null,null,null);
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(ALTBEACON_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
    //ahorro de bateria
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);


}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Log.d(TAG,"onBeacon service connect called");

    beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            if (!entryMessageRaised){
                Log.d(TAG,"didEnterRegion" + "Enter Region"+ region.getUniqueId() + " " + region.getId1() + " " + region.getId2() + " " + region.getId3());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            if (!exitMessageRaised){
                Log.d(TAG,"didEnterRegion" + "Enter Region"+ region.getUniqueId() + " " + region.getId1() + " " + region.getId2() + " " + region.getId3());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

        }
    });

    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, final Region region) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (final Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Beacon encontrado");
                        //Log.d(TAG, beacon.getId1().toString());
                        num = beacon.getId1().toString();
                        if (!notified) {
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    SendNotificacion();
                                }
                            }, 1000 * 10);
                            notified = true;
                            //stopBeaconMonitoring(region);
                            url = "https://cloud.easycontext.com/api/list/ibeacon?key=aNC6-qnDB-MQoi-ir3L&appid=a1e5dc13ec177d4d&uuid="+beacon.getId1()+"&major="+beacon.getId2()+"&minor="+beacon.getId3();
                            MostrarBeacon(url);
                        }

                        url = "https://cloud.easycontext.com/api/list/ibeacon?key=aNC6-qnDB-MQoi-ir3L&appid=a1e5dc13ec177d4d&uuid="+beacon.getId1()+"&major="+beacon.getId2()+"&minor="+beacon.getId3();
                        MostrarBeacon(url);



                    }

                    Numerouuid = num;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No start Monitoring iBeacon");
    }
}

public void SendNotificacion(){


    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,intent,0);

    //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //bundle.getParcelableArray("datos");
    //Log.d("traspaso",imagen.getDrawable().toString());

    //construccion de la notificacion

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    builder.setContentTitle("Se ha detectado una proximidad");
    builder.setContentText("has pasado por un punto de proximidad");
    builder.setSubText("has click para mayor informacion");
    long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
    builder.setVibrate(vibrate);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);



    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICACION_ID,builder.build());
    Toast.makeText(this,"Se detecto proximidad",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //intent.putExtra("titulo",titulo);
    //intent.putExtra("descripcion",descripcion);
    //intent.putExtra("foto",foto);
}

private void stopBeaconMonitoring(Region region){ try {
    beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
    beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
}catch (RemoteException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    Log.d("monitor","stop monitoring");
}

private void startBeaconMonitoring(){
    try {
        beaconRegion = new Region(UNIQUE_ID,null,null,null);
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
        Log.d("monitor","stop monitoring");
    }catch (RemoteException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("monitor","stop monitoring");
}

public void MostrarBeacon(String url) {

    //if (url == null){
   //     Toast.makeText(this,"no escanea proximidad repetida",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // }else {


        requestQueue = new Volley().newRequestQueue(this);


        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        try {


                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject ProxModel= (JSONObject)response.get(i);
                                ProximidadModel pm = new ProximidadModel();

                                pm.setTitle(ProxModel.getString("title"));
                                datos.add(pm);
                                Log.d("datos", datos.toString());
                                title.setText(ProxModel.getString("title"));
                            /*
                            titulo = Zone.get("title").toString();
                            descripcion = Zone.get("description").toString();
                            foto = Zone.get("image").toString();
                            adapter = new BeaconAdapter(datos, MainActivity.this);
                            //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            SendNotificacion();*/

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isBluetoothEnabled();
}

public void isBluetoothEnabled() {
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para mantenerlo en el fondo, necesitas implementar una clase de Application y registrarla en tu ApplicationManifest.xml como:

(Discúlpeme porque mi español no es bueno.)

```
public class MyApplicationName extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, RangeNotifier {
  private static final String TAG = ".MyApplicationName";
  private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "App started up");
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    Region region = new Region("com.example.myapp.boostrapRegion", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
  }

  @Override
  public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    beaconManager.rangeNotifier = this;
  }

  @Override
  public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
  }

  @Override
  public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, final Region region) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (final Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Beacon encontrado");
                    //Log.d(TAG, beacon.getId1().toString());
                    num = beacon.getId1().toString();
                    if (!notified) {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                SendNotificacion();
                            }
                        }, 1000 * 10);
                        notified = true;
                        //stopBeaconMonitoring(region);
                        url = "https://cloud.easycontext.com/api/list/ibeacon?key=aNC6-qnDB-MQoi-ir3L&appid=a1e5dc13ec177d4d&uuid="+beacon.getId1()+"&major="+beacon.getId2()+"&minor="+beacon.getId3();
                        MostrarBeacon(url);
                    }

                    url = "https://cloud.easycontext.com/api/list/ibeacon?key=aNC6-qnDB-MQoi-ir3L&appid=a1e5dc13ec177d4d&uuid="+beacon.getId1()+"&major="+beacon.getId2()+"&minor="+beacon.getId3();
                    MostrarBeacon(url);



                }

                Numerouuid = num;
            }
        });
  }        



  @Override
  public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
  }        

  ...
}
```

Comment: tengo que trasladar toda la parte de beacons que esta en mainactivity a una nueva clase extendida de application?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas hacer es registrar un servicio para que corra en background. Creas la clase que extienda de `IntentService` y lanzas tu clase que contiene la información de tu beacon. Este servicio puede ser lanzado desde un `BroadcastReceiver` cuando detectes que hay conexión al Bluetooth o cuando tu quieras.

por ejemplo:

```
public class BeaconService extends IntentService {

Handler mHandler;

public BeaconService() {

    super("BeaconService");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    //manda llamar la clase que implementa la deteccion de beacons.
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Beacons obeacons=new Beacons(getApplicationContext());
            obeacons.onCreate();


        }
    });

}
}
```

y registras este servicio en el manifest.

```
 <!--Service declared in manifest -->

        <service android:name="com.project.convencion.Aplicacion.BeaconService"
            android:enabled="true"/>
```